# TABLEVIEW cómo mostrar con python34 una tabla sqlite3 en un frame de un formulario UI en Qt4? no lo consigo con TABLEVIEW

Tags: python, uitableview, pyqt4

Primero avisar que soy novato en python. Me he mirado muchos tutoriales, pero ninguno habla de mostrar tablas en formularios .ui. Lo más cercano que encontré fué uno que pasaba el formulario UI a python y luego mostraba la tabla...pero lo que busco es hacerlo sin convertir la tabla a python...

https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2127-aplicaciones-con-base-de-datos-sqlite-pyqt-y-qt-desginer/

#

Otra cosa parecida es mostrar la tabla con QTableWidget, en este ejemplo:
http://www.pythondiario.com/2014/11/aplicacion-grafica-con-pyqt4-y-sqlite3.html

...pero yo busco LO MISMO pero con TABLEVIEW...?...Cómo cambiarlo?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Aplicacion grafica con sqlite3
# www.pythondiario.com
# http://www.pythondiario.com/2014/11/aplicacion-grafica-con-pyqt4-y-sqlite3.html

import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

# Cargar nuestro archivo .ui
form_class = uic.loadUiType("conBase2.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
  QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
  self.setupUi(self)
  self.btn_Guardar.clicked.connect(self.btn_Guardar_clicked)
  self.btn_Cargar.clicked.connect(self.btn_Cargar_clicked)
  self.IniciarBase()


 def IniciarBase(self):
  self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
  self.cursor = self.con.cursor()
  self.cursor.execute ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS campos(NOMBRE TEXT NOT NULL, APELLIDO TEXT NOT NULL, LOCALIDAD TEXT NOT NULL)""" )
  self.con.commit()

 # Evento del boton Guardar
 def btn_Guardar_clicked(self):

  self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
  self.cursor = self.con.cursor()

  # Datos
  self.nombre = str(self.lineEdit.text())
  self.apellido = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
  self.localidad = str(self.lineEdit_3.text())
  self.datos = (self.nombre, self.apellido, self.localidad)

  # Inserta los datos en la tabla campos
  self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO campos (nombre, apellido, localidad) VALUES (?,?,?)", self.datos)
  self.con.commit()

  # Quedan los campos vacios al guardar cliente
  self.lineEdit.setText("")
  self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
  self.lineEdit_3.setText("")

  self.con.commit()
  self.con.close()

 # Evento del boton Caragar
 def btn_Cargar_clicked(self):

  self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
  self.cursor = self.con.cursor()

  # Se cargan los datos indicados de la tabla
  self.cursor.execute("SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDO, LOCALIDAD FROM campos")

  # Al presionar el boton lo primero es borrar todos los datos
  self.lista.clear()

  # Se agregan los elementos al QListWidget
  for i in self.cursor:
   self.nombre = str(i[0])
   self.apellido = str(i[1])
   self.localidad = str(i[2]) 

   self.lista.addItem(self.nombre + " - " + self.apellido + " - " + self.localidad)

  self.con.commit()
  self.con.close()


# iniciar la interfaz gráfica
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MyWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
MyWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

#

En mi caso tengo esto: (abreviado):

Tengo un formulario creado con Qt4 en el que aparecen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>731</width>
    <height>438</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Connect</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0" colspan="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbnMostrarProyectos">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Mostrar Proyectos Guardados en la Tabla</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
```

#

```
  <item row="2" column="0" rowspan="9" colspan="3">
   <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
  </item>
```

#

Y en el archivo python34 que lo llama:

```
    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
    model.setTable("proyectos")
    model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    model.select()
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una forma de hacerlo abajo. Con más conocimiento acerca de cómo quieres visualizar la tabla de datos y de cómo quieres interactuar con estos datos a través del View, se puede generar un modelo más acorde (por ejemplo estoy forzando de mala manera que el view se actualice). Traté de modificar lo menos posible el código que mostraste.

Código:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # Aplicacion grafica con sqlite3
    # www.pythondiario.com
    # http://www.pythondiario.com/2014/11/aplicacion-grafica-con-pyqt4-y-sqlite3.html

    import sys
    import sqlite3
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

    # Cargar nuestro archivo .ui
    form_class = uic.loadUiType("conBase.ui")[0]

    class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.btn_Guardar.clicked.connect(self.btn_Guardar_clicked)
            self.btn_Cargar.clicked.connect(self.btn_Cargar_clicked)
            self.IniciarBase()
            self._modelo = MyTableModel(["NOMBRE", "APELLIDO", "LOCALIDAD"])
            self.lista.setModel(self._modelo)


        def IniciarBase(self):
            self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
            self.cursor = self.con.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS campos(NOMBRE TEXT NOT NULL, APELLIDO TEXT NOT NULL, LOCALIDAD TEXT NOT NULL)""" )
            self.con.commit()

        # Evento del boton Guardar
        def btn_Guardar_clicked(self):

            self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
            self.cursor = self.con.cursor()

            # Datos
            self.nombre = str(self.lineEdit.text())
            self.apellido = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            self.localidad = str(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            self.datos = (self.nombre, self.apellido, self.localidad)

            # Inserta los datos en la tabla campos
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO campos (nombre, apellido, localidad) VALUES (?,?,?)", self.datos)
            self.con.commit()

            # Quedan los campos vacios al guardar cliente
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
            self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
            self.lineEdit_3.setText("")

            self.con.commit()
            self.con.close()

      # Evento del boton Caragar
        def btn_Cargar_clicked(self):

            self.con = sqlite3.connect("./pruebaconBase2.bd")
            self.cursor = self.con.cursor()

            # Se cargan los datos indicados de la tabla
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDO, LOCALIDAD FROM campos")

            # Al presionar el boton lo primero es borrar todos los datos
            self.lista.model().clear()

            # Se agregan los elementos al QListWidget
            for i in self.cursor:
                self.nombre = str(i[0])
                self.apellido = str(i[1])
                self.localidad = str(i[2]) 

                self._modelo.Table.append([self.nombre, self.apellido, self.localidad])
                self._modelo.layoutChanged.emit()



            self.con.commit()
            self.con.close()

    class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
        def __init__(self, headers, table = None, parent = None):
            super(MyTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
            if not table:
                self._table = []
            else:
                self._table = table
            self._headers = headers

        Table = property(lambda s: s._table)

        def rowCount(self, parent = None):
            return len(self._table)

        def columnCount(self, parent = None):
            return len(self._headers)

        def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                if index.isValid():
                    row = index.row()
                    col = index.column()
                    if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
                        if 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
                            return self._table[row][col]

        def headerData(self, section, orientation, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return None
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if 0 <= section < self.columnCount():
                    return str(self._headers[section])
                else:
                    None
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                if len(self._table) < 1: return ""
                if 0 <= section < len(self._table):
                    return str(section + 1)

        def clear(self):
            self._table = []


    # iniciar la interfaz gráfica
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
    MyWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```